# Finding the radius of convergence of a power series involving legendre polynomials

Tags: power-series, special-functions, legendre-polynomials

I am trying to find the radius of convergence for $f(x,t)=\sum P_n(x)t^n$ considered as a power series in $t$ as a function of $x$. Here $P_n(x)$ are the legendre polynomials on the interval $[-1,1]$.  I know that each $|P_n(x)| \leq 1$. So I know that the radius of convergence is at least $1$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$ by dominating it by the geometric series. But I am wondering if the radius of convergence can increase.

More precisely I want to find the radius of convergence as a function of $x$. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If all you know is that $P_n(x) \le 1$, then it could be the case that $P_n(x) = 0$,

Comment: Are $P_n$ the Legendre polynomials on some interval, as suggested by a label?

Comment: @mrf yes it could be the case and also $P_n(x)$ can be zero

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks for pointing out I meant legendre polynomials on $[-1,1]$

Comment: But [you know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) that $f(x,t)=1/\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}$, so the answer is direct, yes?

Comment: @Did so can I just use that formula and solve for $|2xt-t^2|<1$ and get it.

Comment: @Did one of the reasons I am so sceptical of this is because of the rearrangements involved in getting the generating function